# Zing Chart Memory Leak, causing browser to crash

Tags: memory-leaks

We are currently rendering 50-100 canvas on browser window. Browsers both IE and chrome crashes. 
On further investigation, looks like memory is creeping up steadily. Causing browser to crash.

We are building a solution to print charts To achieve this,

1. We are displaying all the charts in a simple page (iframe) charts are not visible to user
2. Using chart id to getting image data.
3. Since charts are not visible we can ‘destroy’ or remove them from memory once they are rendered.
4. But ‘destroy’ does not reduce charts memory footprint
5. Tried setting object to null. this did not work either

Attached snippet for your reference,

```
var runner = 0
zingchart.complete = function (dataObj) {
    for (i = 0; i < ZingChartCollection.length; i++) {
        if (dataObj["id"] == ZingChartCollection[i].ChartId) {
            var data = zingchart.exec(dataObj["id"], "getimagedata", '{"filetype": "png"}');
            zingchart.exec(dataObj["id"], 'destroy');
            zingchart.exec();
            if (runner < 200) {
                document.getElementById("displayCount").value = runner;
                render();
            }
            else {
                //zingchart = null;
            }
            runner++;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a note regarding the issue from the ZinChart dev team:

---

The issue here is that the render() -> complete event -> image generation -> destroy() is a closed loop.

The way the ZingChart lib works, in order to fire the complete as soon as possible, the code was binding the context menu events AFTER the complete was fired. 
So, since destroy was being called immediately, the context menu events were left out in the open, and with 50-100 charts it starts to add, leading to memory leaks.

This will be changed & fixed in the next versions in order to fire the complete event after the context menu setup, however, with the current setup, there are two options:

1. use mode:static on render() since the idea is to get the static image out of the chart. This skips event binding so memory leak will no longer be an issue. 
   Also, since less canvas objects will be used, this will dramatically decrease the memory needed per chart.
2. if you need the complete functionality of the charts (although not needed in this particular case), call the destroy() in a delayed function via setTimeout. This will allow 
   for the context menu events to be set, so destroy() will also unbind them.

Comment: Thanks, ZingChart, did get back to me with these suggestions. However, below are few other issues...
1. In certain cases, 'Complete' event, is fired more than once. So in these instances image data is blank or incomplete.
2. In certain case full image data is not transfered. 

It would be great if 'complete' event is fired once for a chart and also provides complete image data. Hope this is incorporated in ZingCharts next release